# Redirect 302 doesn't work with API Gateway and Swagger Open API

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to redirect users using Api Gateway + Lambda Proxy and also using Swagger open Api.

Here is my lambda, pretty simple:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const response = {
    statusCode: 302,
    headers: {
      Location: 'https://google.com', # just an example, it's not hardcoded like this
    }
  };

  return callback(null, response);
}
```

I also tried 301 but didn't work.

Here is my swagger.yaml

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: xpt
  description: xpt
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /{hash}:
    get:
      responses:
        "302":
          description: Redirect
        "404":
          description: Not found
        "500":
          description: Error
      x-amazon-apigateway-auth:
        type: none
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:${region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${region}:${aws_account_id}:function:${mylambda}/invocations
        responses:
            default:
              statusCode: "302"
        httpMethod: POST
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_templates
        payloadFormatVersion: 1.0
```

I also made a custom dns for my api gateway like `https://example.com`

When the user sends a request to this endpoint, e.g `https://example.com/asdhoSHA`, it returns the 302 code and the header location as expected, but the user it's being redirected to `https://example.com/https://google.com`. It's concatenating both URLs.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?